# MATLAB does not read csv file completely

Tags: matlab, csv

I am reading a csv file into memory in my MATLAB program, and the last line of the file is not being read.

The end of the csv file looks like this:

```
30000,0.99534,1.4E-07,0.001945
40000,0.997967,4.74E-08,0.000656
50000,0.998953,2.02E-08,0.000279
75000,0.999713,4.19E-09,5.8E-05
100000,1,1.36E-09,1.9E-05
```

When I use `readmatrix` from the r2019a standard library, it works and reads every line. When I used `csvread` with only the filename as an argument, for some reason the last line of the file is not read.

When I use csvread, this is the result.

```
>> dat = csvread('../data/black_body.csv');
>> dat(end, :)

ans =

   1.0e+04 *

   7.5000    0.0001    0.0000    0.0000
```

And in the file `black_body.csv`, the final line is

```
100000,1,1.36E-09,1.9E-05
```

Why is matlab not reading the last line of the file?

edit: Here is the link to the csv file.

[link](https://pastebin.com/uJ6NT8gg)

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem, can you link the CSV file ?

Comment: I edited the question to include the link at the bottom.

Comment: What if you add a newline after the last record?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the CSV file and it has a problem on the fourth line.
There is a "." which makes a shift on the whole data after this line.

Original CSV: 
800,1.6E-05,0..991126E-7,0.001372

Revised CSV: 
800,1.6E-05,0.991126E-7,0.001372

After the CSV file correction, I was able to get the correct result using `csvread`.

```
dat(end, :)

ans =

   1.0e+05 *

    1.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't imagine how long it took you to find that. Have a great day!